# Windows 10 v2004 build 19041.329 gives EACCES on port listen

Tags: windows-10, networking

I've been developing on Windows for quite some while, but ever since updating to the latest Windows version, I've been getting random issues with EACCES errors when spinning up my Node.js project.

The error first occurred when I updated my Windows to enable WSL2 support for Docker. Docker is disabled on boot, so I think I can eliminate this as an issue.

Regardless of booting PhpStorm that tries to listen on port 9000 for Xdebug, or starting Node.js for API development through Git Bash (not sure if relevant), I'm prompted with permission denied errors on binding ports.

The first errors occurred when attempting to bind to 0.0.0.0:9000 and 0.0.0.0:3000, but even after changing this to 127.0.0.1:3000, the problems still occur.

I also randomly get issues when shutting down my computer, telling me that vpnkit.exe is blocking the shutdown, again, not sure if this is relevant.

Running netstat with `netstat -naob | findstr 3000` also yields no results, just like `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000).OwningProcess` does.

Is there any way to debug the specific issue at hand, get more information *why* the port cannot be bound, or what could be blocking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved after disabling Hyper-V. The solution I tried can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62061654/2248679)